# how to Select fileds in different dataset from Different DataSource

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

i have two Data Sources. Each DataSource has some DataSets. What i want is a tablix to retrieve data from different datasets of those two DataSources. But it seems like that in a tablix i can just select one datasource at the same time. I cannot change datasource after select it.

I've tried the sql for each DataSource, there is no problem. But i have no idea about how to select different datasets from two different DataSources.

Appreciated for any suggestion!

Comment: Do you need multiple rows to be generated from both datasets?

Comment: I just need one row, i can only select one datasource

Answer (score 0):

You can select from more than one datasource if you use the expression editor for each field's value.

In the editor, click on "Datasets" in the lower left box (called "Category:"), and choose the dataset you want to get the value from in the lower middle box, and then in the lower right box, choose the field from that dataset that you want to get.

You will have to choose some aggregate function on the field, because when you use multiple datasets this way, you can't expect the tablix to be able to populate one table row per data row.   But if your dataset only returns one row, you can simply use the First() function for pretty much any value you want to get.